# Please correct me with OOP inheritance

Tags: c#, oop

I thought it will call the derived class function because class will give importance to its own function but it is calling base class function please correct me...

```
class Baseclass
{
  public void fun()
  {
    Console.Write("Base class" + " ");
  }
}
class Derived1 : Baseclass
{
  new void fun()
  {
    Console.Write("Derived1 class" + " ");
  }
}
class Derived2 : Derived1
{
  new void fun()
  {
    Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
  }
}
class test
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Derived2 d = new Derived2();
    d.fun(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a language tag to your question :)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class method is called because only the base class method is *accessible*.

Why aren't the other methods accessible? Let's look at the method in `Derived2`:

```
new void fun()
{
  Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
}
```

What is its access modifier? None, so it defaults to `private`. This means that you can't access this method from `test` class!

To make it work, simply add a `public` modifer:

```
new public void fun()
{
  Console.Write("Derived2 class" + " ");
}
```